# How to translate strings with link in email template (Magento2)

Tags: magento2, email-templates, localisation

I'm trying to translate

```
{{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>' store_email=$store_email |raw}}.
```

with this line in the .csv

```
"If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>","Für Rückfragen stehen wir Ihnen jederzeit gerne zur Verfügung. Sie erreichen uns per E-Mail unter <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>"
```

But it doesn't work. I have no problem with this one

```
{{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Translate string containing "](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144688/translate-string-containing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use double quotes when a translation string already has or needs quotes (for example: attributes for inline translation html elements) - like this:

```
"If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href=""mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>"","Für Rückfragen stehen wir Ihnen jederzeit gerne zur Verfügung. Sie erreichen uns per E-Mail unter <a href=""mailto:%store_email"">%store_email</a>""
```