# Translate string containing "

Tags: magento-2.1, inline-translations

I am busy translating several strings on my webshop, and I encountered this string:

```
You subscribe to "General Subscription".
```

How do I translate this string? I tried this:

```
"You subscribe to "General Subscription".","U staat ingeschreven voor de standaard nieuwsbrief inschrijving.","module","Magento_Customer"
```

But that doesn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
 "You subscribe to ""General Subscription"".","U staat ingeschreven voor de standaard nieuwsbrief inschrijving.","module","Magento_Customer
```

Comment: Both did not work :/

Comment: Still not working

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen, Please check it again